# Examples of functions satisfying two particular properties

Tags: functions

Give some examples of a general function $f(a,b)$ with $b > 0$ satisfying the following two properties:

1. $f(a,b) > a$;
2. $f(a_1, b) - f(a_2, b) \leq a_1 - a_2$.

Obviously $f(a, b) = a + g(b)$ with $g(b) > 0$ satisfies those two properties. Are there any other examples except for $f(a, b) = a + g(b)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there are no other examples.

If (2) is true for all $a_1$ and $a_2$, then it must be true with $a_1$ and $a_2$ interchanged, i.e.
$$ f(a_2,b) - f(a_1,b) \le a_2 - a_1$$
Combined with (2), this says $f(a_1, b) - f(a_2, b) = a_1 - a_2$,
and thus $f(a,b) - a$ is the same for all $a$.  If we let $f(a,b) - a = g(b)$, that says $f(a,b) = a + g(b)$.